# Remove the Background Activity Task in Android which only Task Create But Activity Never Focus

Tags: android, android-activity

In My App, When i am start creating New Activity-1 as singleInstance. So, it follow below Steps in Android Execution.
(So, Stack look like **TASK-A(10000099)-> Activity-1**)

1. I am_create_task: [10,10000099]
2. I am_create_activity: [10,225706045,10000099,...]

*So, before Task A: 1000099 complete the other process to create activity*

I am Launching Another New Activity-2 as SingleInstance.
(Stack look like **TASK-B -> Activity-2** on Foreground while TASK-A with it's activity in Background). Android Execution to create TASK-B and it's Activity-2 as follow.

1. am_create_task: [10,1000100]
2. am_create_activity
3. am_create_called
4. am_start_called
5. am_resume_gained

TASK-B on foreground and than i finish Activity-2 which placed in TASK-B. Hence, TASK-B finished.

6. am_finish_activity
7. I am_destroy_activity
8. I am_remove_task: [1000100,125]

Here is Issue: Now, the TASK-A which left between the process android brings into foreground with below log.

***I am_focused_stack: [10,0,124,127,finishActivity adjustFocus adjustFocusToNextFocusableStack]***

After this, all the activity process executed and  TASK-A -> Activity-1 Become Foreground.

It seems TASK creates and execute based on LIFO as Back Stack activities.

Now, how to stop pop-up of TASK-A and it's Activity-1. I want to finish it in Background only. How to Achieve this.

NOTE: noHistory, clearTaskOnLaunch and finishOnTaskLaunch is not working at all.